# Why do my clothes acquire a bad "dog smell" after laying in the wardrobe for a long time?

Tags: dogs, hygiene, shedding

We proudly own a 3 year-old mix of Labrador and golden retriever. We care about her, and regularly wash her using the appropriate shampoo for dogs.

The dog itself never has any kind of unpleasant smell on her fur. She loses a lot of fur, but not more than average for her breed(s). Still though, we've noticed that some of the clothes hanging bit longer in the wardrobe will start accumulating a dog odor.

What causes this odor and how can I remove it? It's not somehow connected with her health, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some areas where pets can be found often may have odor associated with them, even if your pets are well groomed.

There are different ways to [make your clothes smell good](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Clothes-Smell-Good) without washing them, and to keep your closet smelling fresh.

[PetMD](http://www.petmd.com/dog/care/evr_dg_how_to_remove_the_smell_of_dog_without_removing_the_dog) also has a good article on how to rid your whole house of dog smell, which will help with your clothes as well.

> Start off by taking all of the furniture apart – pillows, blankets and the like – and vacuuming everything thoroughly. If the sofa and chairs have removable slipcovers or cushion covers, take those off for washing (details later). Get into the crevices of the furniture as deep as possible to remove all the hair, and flip the bed mattress to get both sides. On the floors, make sure to get under all of the furniture and in the corners, where “hair bunnies” tend to gather.
>
> Next, gather your deodorizing supplies. It’s simple; all you need is a big box or two of baking soda and a bottle of apple cider vinegar. Wash all of your linens, blankets and cushion covers in a mix of oxy powered laundry detergent and a ¼ cup of apple cider vinegar. There are also pet odor removers available at pet supply stores, but generally speaking, they are not much more effective than the home remedies.
>
> On the carpets, bed and furniture, sprinkle baking soda liberally, using a cleaning brush to spread it around and into the fabric. Let it all sit overnight so that the baking soda has a chance to absorb the odors.

[image]

From personal experience with my two labs, it helps to have a small air filter running.  Periodically washing articles around the house that may have accumulated smell such as carpets will help as well.  There are many [natural remedies](http://everydayroots.com/pet-stain-and-odor-removal) to remove pet odor that may also be of interest.